# standalone nodejs client connects to a self signed websocket (wss)

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, websocket

I have a node server (Meteor.js) that should communicate with another server using websockets.
As the communication is between servers that don't involve direct users, I've chosen to use a self signed certificate.

Where to add the certificate parameters from the node server (which is a client to the other server)

```
var soc = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:9000")
```

I've tested connecting in insecure mode with certification and it works fine.

```
var soc = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000")
```

Connecting from android application in secure mode after adding the certificates to the application works fine too.

Comment: The easiest way would be to use NGINX to handle the Secure Connections, you also never need a self-signed cert, use a certificate issued by [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)!

Here are some guides on NGINX as a reverse Proxy and NGINX with LE:
[LE and NGINX](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04), [Node and NGINX](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Hope I could help you!

Comment: Thanks, but If I use a self signed certificate from Let's Encrypt, I won't even need NGINX.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've found this solution, the part that allows the client to connect to a secure socket with a self-signed certificate is:

> "rejectUnauthorized: false"

It accepts all certificates but it still keeps the connection encrypted.

```html
'use strict';
var WebSocket = require('ws');

var soc = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:9000", {
  protocolVersion: 8,
  origin: 'https://localhost:9000',
  rejectUnauthorized: false
});

console.log("launched");
soc.onopen = function (event) {
  console.log("Sending message");
  soc.send('{}');
};

soc.onmessage = function (event) {
  console.log(event.data);
}
soc.on('error', function(event) {
      console.log(event);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple solution, add below line at top level of file (just after import section).

```
process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;
```

But you must be aware that, though data send / received are encrypted, still this is insecure as anybody with self signed root ca certificate can connect to application.